# jquery cloning. click event not triggering on newly created cloned rows

Tags: jquery, cloning

This code is working fine, almost
Lets say I have 10 rows on a table, I click on top row, it gets CLONED and then ADDED to the bottom of table and the original is REMOVED, repeat these steps 5 times. 
I now end with the five rows that were cloned on bottom.

Now If i click on the first cloned row, it should clone, and get added to bottom, but the click Event is not firing up.

```
$('.tog').live('click', function() {
   var $btn = $('#'+dataId);
   var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone();

   $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function(){
      this.id += '_clone';
   });

   $btn.closest('tbody').append( $clonedRow );

   $("#"+dataId1).remove();
});
```

Comment: Look at the method params http://api.jquery.com/clone/ and all should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing:

```
var $clonedRow = $btn.closest('tr').clone(true);
```